# Passing the text from inside a span to a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery, I'm trying to work out a way to send the words inside a span to a popup that appears when mousing over, I'm not sure sure how to send the text. I have the popup appearing, but I cant send the text.

So in this example I'd like the popup (class="popup") simply to say **Hello World**.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="text" data-id="#text1">Hello World</span>
<div class="popup" id="text1">This should just say Hello World, so this popup is wrong.</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".text", function() {
 var id = $(this).data('id');
 $(id).fadeIn();
}).on('mouseout', '.text', function() {
 var id = $(this).data('id');
 $(id).fadeOut();   
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.text {background-color: red}
.popup {display: none}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6Pp9w/33/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/6Pp9w/34/)**  change the text of the popup using [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

### Add this line to your js:

```
 $(id).text($(this).text());
```